# Run macro automatically on extension of table

Tags: vba

[Sheet-DropDown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qo1m.png)
[Sheet-Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jFaE.png)
Please refer to the images and code
I have a button "Refresh DropDown Validation" which assigns values in column A of "Dropdown" sheet to values in column A of "Input" sheet on clicking the button "Refresh DropDown Validation".
This button currently assigns the values until row number 2874, the row till which the table exists. To add more entries, the user has to extend the table for e.g till row 3000 and then again click "Refresh DropDown Validation" button. Until the user clicks this button, row number 2875 to row number 3000 will contain no values which are causing me a problem
What I want is that as soon as the user extends the table from row 2874 to row 3000, the values get allocated automatically.

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")
Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DropDown")

LastRow1 = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox LastRow

LastRowAT = sht1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox LastRowAT


For i = 2 To LastRow1 + 1
    With sht.Range("A" & i).Validation
        .delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=DropDown!A2:A" & LastRowAT
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = "Value not present in drop down."
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: You don't need a Macro for this Task. You need a [Dynamic](https://www.excelcampus.com/tips/dynamic-data-validation/) Data Validation List. Which will automatically update the Validation list. Follow the link to set it up.

Comment: This link Covers both Method. I personally prefer the 2nd Method in this [Link](https://excelchamps.com/blog/dynamic-drop-down-list/)

Comment: @Mikku Is there no other way to accomplish this using a macro I created? Because my main task cannot be accomplished using the methods defined in the link